# How can i fix this pycord code project i made?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have a discord bot project. In the following code I made that if you reply a specific word the bot will give you a role. I already created the role but when I try it turn out to a error.

I'm using Pycord.

Code:

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def money(ctx):
    await ctx.send("How much money you have?")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == "100,000" and m.author == ctx.author

    role_input = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Rich")
    await role_input.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{role_input.author.mention}, you have been given the 'Rich' role.")
```

I was trying to make a slash command that the bot will reply "How much money you have?" and if you reply the specific word "100,000" then the bot will grant you a role.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "the application did not response"

Comment: Please edit the title to help others in the future find this question if they have the same issue. "How can i fix this pycord code project i made?" is EXTREMELY vague. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the title if others need help with pycord.

Comment: Please don't do that, the question is already marked as solved by accepting an answer.

Comment: But do update the title to better describe the specific problem you had.

Comment: oh alright then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting "the application did not respond" is because you're never responding to the application command. As your command could probably take a while waiting for the user to respond, we can use `await ctx.defer()` to defer our response and then use `await ctx.followup.send` to send the followup message and respond. If you didn't use `defer`, you could also use `ctx.response.send_message` or `ctx.respond` in cases where the command doesn't take too long to execute.

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def money(ctx):
    # deferring as it might take us a while
    await ctx.defer()

    await ctx.send("How much money you have?")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == "100,000" and m.author == ctx.author

    role_input = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Rich")
    await role_input.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.followup.send(f"{role_input.author.mention}, you have been given the 'Rich' role.")
```

Comment: thanks you, it working for replying to user if they run it but when the bot ask "How much money you have?" it have the slash command up of it running "vz4 is thinking..." is there a way to remove that?

Comment: and when user replying it don't do anything (my bot have admin perms and the role is created)

Comment: What message are you sending after invoking the slash command?

Comment: i'm sending: 100,000